# How to change font for content script in chrome extension

Tags: css, google-chrome-extension

I am injecting some HTML into a page via content script, and want to change the font for the same. So far I have done `"web_accessible_resources": ["images/*", "fonts/*"]` in my manifest, and in my css corresponding to my content script, I have done:

```
@font-face{
    font-family: Trench;
    src: url('chrome-extension://__MSG_@@extension_id__/fonts/trench.otf') format(opentype);
}
```

The HTML gets injected into the page properly, and I get no errors in the console either. The font remains the default font, and doesn't change as desired.

An observation I've made, is that if I give the wrong URL, like for instance I change some characters to wrong ones, I still wont get any error. I don't know the reason for this could be.

Another observation: If, in a selector, I give an existing font, such as `font-family: "Verdana"`, then it changes properly. So the problem narrows down to "Trench" not getting loaded, isn't it?

Comment: If that code applies, a new `@font-face` is added to the page. Does it apply to anything? Not exactly. You'd need `some-selector {font-family: 'Trench'}` for that, right? What is your question?

Comment: Yes, I've done this, and it still doesn't work.

Comment: Sounds wired , can you share little bit more code from your extension please ?